# Android Backup / Restore of Data Partition

Tags: android

I am trying to backup and restore the entire data partition for an android device. The device does not have a recovery app (such as cwm) and the restore needs to happen via click from an app that I have written. I have gotten this to work in the past by communicating with CWM to do a data partition restore, but I do not have this option now.

Of course looking for recomendations, but also thoughts on the following:

```
dd if=/dev/mtd/mtd5 of=/sdcard/data.img bs=4096
```

then to restore

```
dd if=/sdcard/data.img of=/dev/mtd/mtd5 bs=4096
```

Either this or by using cat xxx >> yyy

I am not sure however, what will happen if I try to write the data partition while the system is running. I was thinking I will write it then reboot.. hope for the best?

Thanks!

EDIT:
How about:

```
cat /dev/mtd/mtd5 >> /sdcard/data.img
flash_image userdata /sdcard/data.img
```

Comment: This is not only not possible without root, but please please please don't do this unless you know what you're doing. You're just asking to brick someone's phone.

Comment: Yes it does require root. As for bricking someones phone, this is not for a public app or even a public phone. We use these devices internally and need this functionality for the privacy and security of our users. This wouldn't be an issue if the manufacturer respected open source licenses and gave out the source codes for the kernel and OS, but they are holding us hostage unless we order 5000 units or more. I am actually hoping the community will show the manufacturer that us little companies matter too.